# Apache Camel Batch FTP Upload then disconnect

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

My use case is to poll a local directory for a list of new files periodically, and then upload them to a FTP server in 1 connection. The Camel route is defined in Spring XML as follows:

```
<route>
  <from uri="file:data/inbox?noop=true&amp;delay=1000&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=3" />
  <to uri="ftp:uid:xxxxx@host:21/data?disconnect=false"/>
</route>
```

The route is functioning well, except that the FTP connection will retain connected until the FTP server timeout my connection. I hope to reuse the same connection to upload a batch of files and then close the connection immediately when the last file in the batch completed the upload. How can achieve this in Camel?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible currently. You will need to write some code to do the disconnect yourself.

You are welcome to log a JIRA to enhance this in camel-ftp: https://issues.apache.org/activemq/browse/CAMEL. For example a new option to disconnectOnBatchComplete.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created a JIRA case https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10083

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way but it is not pretty.

You could try to wrap your route based on a cronSchedulePolicy. So say you kick start the route once every hour and poll the directory and send the files. Then you simply add a stop(). Not sure if the stop is exactly the same in the xml dsl. Alternatively, you could also write that `onExchangeComplete(new Processor(StopProcessor(routeId))` and inside that processor you via `exchange.getContext.stopRoute(routeid)` stop the route. Again this depends on your requirements allow you to do this.

```
<route>
  <from uri="file:data/inbox?noop=true&amp;delay=1000&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=3" />
  <to uri="ftp:uid:xxxxx@host:21/data?disconnect=false"/>
<stop/>
</route>
```